# Semantically Identical JSONB Object Passed Into Postgres Function Cannot Be Parsed When Using Placeholders

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, node-postgres

I have two identical JSON objects.

| First Object | Second Object |
| --- | --- |
| [{"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}] | [{"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}] |

However, postgres (or at least PgAmdin 4) isn't treating them the same when it comes to calling a postgres function...

When I call the function directly from pgadmin4 like so:

```sql
select * from myfunction(123, abc, '[{"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}]')
```

**notice the ' marks surrounding the object** everything works perfectly.

However, when I call the postgres function from an AWS Lambda function written in node js like so:

```js
let callfunction = `SELECT * FROM myfunction($1, $2, $3)`;
const dataResult = await client.query(callfunction, [123, abc, '[{"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}]']);
```

This fails, saying:

> invalid input syntax for type json

I my mind, they are identical function calls--the javascript SHOULD build an identical query, anyway.

However, there is something strange when it comes to this placeholder, because not matter what combination of characters, apostrophes etc, it will always fail.

The ONLY way I have been able to get this to work is to just include the object in the actual function call itself like so:

```js
let callfunction = `SELECT * FROM myfunction($1, $2, '[{"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}]')`;
```

Again, this "works" but is an obviously a BIG no-no in when it comes to sql injection vulnerability mitigation...

Why does this function call behave like this when parameterized?

Comment: Could you share the piece of SQL that is sent to the database? The one that fails. Check the PostgreSQL log or your own error log

Comment: @FrankHeikens yes I'd be happy to. Just to be clear, you're looking for the SQL query itself or the function code itself

Comment: No, just the query that is created by your code, and the parameters sent by your code, to the database. It should be in the logs.

Comment: What's up with `const sanitizedBody = event.body.replace(/'/g, "''");`? Are you actually using that somewhere? This looks wrong.

Comment: @Bergi apologies, I've removed that unused constant in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the issue, this code should indeed work. Notice that the apostrophes have nothing to do with the error message, and they serve different purposes anyway: in SQL code they delimit the SQL literal and would be escaped as `''`, whereas in JavaScript code they delimit the string literal and would be escaped as `\'`.

However, two suggestions:

- Use `::json` to specify the type of the parameter, to make sure any potential `myfunction` overload is resolved correctly:

  ```js
  let callfunction = `SELECT * FROM myfunction($1, $2, $3::json)`;
  ```
- Use `JSON.stringify`, not a literal json string, to make sure you're passing valid JSON:

  ```js
  const value = [
    {"id": 123,"firstname": "Mike","lastname": "Smith","ani": 123456,"email": "fakeemail@f.com"}
  ];
  const dataResult = await client.query(
    callfunction,
    [123, abc, JSON.stringify(value)]
  );
  ```